# программа не обращается к массиву

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Программа на ассемблере вроде правильно работает, за исключением одного **но**, - она не обращается к массиву, будто я что-то не то передаю.

Код:

```
.model small
.stack 128d
.data 
matrixSize equ 3 ;  задача решается для квадратной матрицы
elementSize equ 2 ; размер элемента массива
matrix  dw  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;матрица

.code
main:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov bx, 0
mov bp, 0
mov cx, matrixSize
Cycle1:
mov si, cx
mov cx, matrixSize
mov dx, 0

mov ax, matrix[bp] ; не обращается к матрице
mov dx, ax
Cycle2:
    mov ax, dx
    sub matrix[bx], ax
    add bx, elementSize
    loop Cycle2
add bp, elementSize*(matrixSize+1)
mov cx, si
loop Cycle1
mov AH, 4Ch
int 21h
end main
```

Задача такая: дана квадратная матрица, надо каждый ее элемент уменьшить на величину диагонального элемента соответствующей строки.

Comment: задача написана, чтобы запускать через tasm.exe

Comment: Почему вы считаете что она не обращается?

Comment: потому что в строчке mov ax, matrix[bp] вместо нулевого элемента (1) в ax передается 0

Comment: Отладчиком посмотрите куда именно он обращается и что именно там находится

Comment: вот вроде показывает, что в ds, где как раз и лежит моя матрица 01 00 02 00 03 00 и тд и тп
но все равно записывает 0 в ax

Comment: @Павел, 1. опишите в вопросе алгоритм, что вы хотите получить? 2. Почему у вас во внешнем цикле bp увеличивается на elementSize*(matrixSize+1) а не просто на elementSize*matrixSize? Так как есть у вас происходит переход не на следующую строку, а на строку + 1 элемент, соответственно внутренний цикл идет уже не только по текущей строке, но и "залезает" на следующую (а в конце вообще выходит за границы массива).

Comment: задача такая: дана квадратная матрица и надо каждый ее элемент уменьшить на величину диагонального элемента соответствующей строки

Comment: @insolor внешний цикл идет по диагональным элементам. согласен. ошибка - должен выполняться на один раз меньше. и внутренний цикл со своим собственным счетчиком. он идет как раз по строчке. а вот все равно даже первый элемент почему-то оказывается нулем

Comment: @Павел, у вас все верно, это я ошибся.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы все верно. Я слегка модифицировал программу, чтобы ее можно было скомпилировать с помощью fasm, отлаживал в dosbox с помощью отладчика afdpro. Значения ячеек правильно записываются в AX, данные изменяются правильно.

Программа (компилируется в com):

```
format binary
use16
org 100h

jmp main

matrixSize equ 3 ;  задача решается для квадратной матрицы
elementSize equ 2 ; размер элемента массива
matrix  dw  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;матрица

main:
    mov bx, 0
    mov bp, 0
    mov cx, matrixSize
    Cycle1:
    mov si, cx
    mov cx, matrixSize
    mov dx, 0

    mov ax, [matrix+bp]
    mov dx, ax
    Cycle2:
        mov ax, dx
        sub [matrix+bx], ax
        add bx, elementSize
        loop Cycle2
    add bp, elementSize*(matrixSize+1)
    mov cx, si
    loop Cycle1

    mov AH, 4Ch
    int 21h
```

Исходное состояние матрицы:
[image: Исходное состояние матрицы]

После команды `mov ax, [matrix+bp]` в AX считалось правильное значение (в данном случае 1):
[image: Состояние регистра AX]

Конечное состояние матрицы (FF FF и FE FF это соответственно -1 и -2):
[image: Конечное состояние матрицы]

Если выполнить операции вручную, то при исходной матрице

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

В конце должно получиться

```
 0  1  2
-1  0  1
-2 -1  0
```

На последнем скриншоте видим именно эти данные.

## Обновление

Все-таки скачал tasm, проверил первоначальный вариант программы на нем.

Проблема была в регистре bp. Как оказалось, при косвенной адресации через него в качестве сегментного регистра используется регистр SS:

> Как и регистры BX, SI и DI, регистр BP также может использоваться в
>   качестве указателя на ячейку памяти, но здесь есть некоторые
>   отличия. Регистры BX, SI и DI обычно  ссылаются  на  память
>   относительно сегментного регистра DS (или, в случае использования в
>   строковых инструкциях регистра DI, относительно сегментного регистра
>   ES), а регистр BP адресуется к памяти относительно регистра SS
>   (сегментный регистр стека).

([Источник](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/asm/tasm/13.php))

Выход - либо явно указывать сегментный регистр (`ds:matrix[bp]`), либо использовать другой индексный регистр, например тот же DI, он по-умолчанию адресует память относительно сегментного регистра DS (кроме строковых операций типа `movs`, `cmps` и прочих, там используется ES).

Ну и скриншот:
[image: скриншот]

Ну и напоследок - почему работала адресация через BP в моём варианте программы? Все просто: я компилировал в COM (модель TINY), поэтому основные сегментные регистры были равны друг другу (cs==ds==ss), т.к. и код, и данные, и стек находятся в одном сегменте.